# Django template and dynamic url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have a few links that I need to link to via a submit button. Let's say that I have links_

```
http://link/problem1 
http://link/problem2
http://link/problem3
```

In my django template I'm trying to link to a random link out of those three: 
So in my django template I have:

**`<a href="http://link/problem" class="btn btn-success"> Some Text </a>`**

Is there a way that I can have a numeric loop that would loop through numbers 1 to 3 and add those numbers to the

**`http://link/problem`**

I have found a few examaples on how to make a numeric for loop in a django template but I dont know how to add those numbers to the link in an a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`center`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#center) default filter to create a string of 3 spaces, then loop over it and use [**`forloop.counter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) in template

```
{% with ''|center:3 as range %}
   {% for _ in range %}
      <a href="http://link/problem{{forloop.counter}}" class="btn btn-success"> Some Text </a>
   {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```